# Dynamic sub nav

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ive created a portfolio website for myself, there is a gallery which users can enter, click on a thumbnail and then go to a new html page with the full image and description. Now on this full image page i have a list of other fullimage pages for project 2,3,4,5, etc..

But obviously manually updating project2.html to have a list of all other projects minius project 2 in the sub nav is very tedious and mistakes will occus when i have to do it for all 12 plus pages. So im after the page people are viewing not to appear in that sub nav.

My problem is.. Do i scrap the custom html site and move onto a cms.. The logical step for this sort of dynamic nav. Or do i try and include php if possible. Can anyone suggest the best approach for this, im aware it might in the longrun be easier to run off a cms but i do like the control i get and knowledge i hand crafted my html.

Thanks
Mat

Comment: Just put navigation into separate file, and include it into all file You need. It's simple way for You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to do this with php, you could do so by making a single file containing the navigation, for example nav.html:

```
<a href="project1.php">Project 1</a>
<a href="project2.php">Project 2</a>
<a href="project3.php">Project 3</a>
```

all the project pages would then need to be php files, with the appropriate .php extension, and in each of them you would have:

```
<p>All your normal page html about the project and such that's above your navigation</p>
<?php
    include("nav.html");
?>
<p>Anything underneath your navigation</p>
```

Alternatively, the CMS is a viable choice, or if you particularly fancied learning some php, you could actually code a perfectly servicable system to do this without too much trouble yourself.

Comment: Do you know of any articles that might help me achieve this, i understand your code, but in i'm not 100% on syntax to get this working in php pages. But this is def what im after, thanks.

Comment: Not many articles that I know of really cover include in much depth apart from the php documentation - http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php - other than that if you have any other specific questions you can always pop another question up on here, or if there was something in the answer you'd like clarifying please say and I'll be happy to throw an edit up to make something more clear.

Comment: Thanks hecksa, could you clarify what syntax i need to wrap things in for instance can i use include in my html page to reference a .php file containing the nav or does my index need to be .php too?  And in the nav.php for instance, would i need anything other than the html links? Ill do some reading later on to try some things, but big thanks. M

Comment: 1) In order to use `include` you need a php script, so any pages with the include have to be .php files. This means index.php, project1.php, etc. The file you are including (the nav data itself) *doesn't* have to be a php file, so it could be nav.html if you like.   
2)No, all you need in the nav is literally the links. Obviously if you want something else to appear every time you use the include you can add whatever you so desire, but there's nothing special you need to put in to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

If your don't want to use CMS , you can create a php file to handle requests for example , a php file that receive this request :

`http://myfolio.com/moreinfo.php?album_id=1&`

now in the php file you can get informatin from DB and folders then create a HTML Stream and then output it.